# Cardinality of the set of functions over the naturals such that $f(n) \geq n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardinality of the set of functions over the naturals such that $f(n) \geq n$ for every $n$?

I know it's not countable and at most $\aleph$ so it should be $\aleph$, but I can't find how to bound it from below using a function. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set of functions $g(n) = f(n) - n$, that is just the set of *all* functions from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, and this is clearly a biyection.

Comment: Oh didn't think about a bijection, thought it would be harder. Why is the set of $g(n)$ is the set of all functions?

Comment: Let $g(n)$ a function over the naturals, then $f(n) = g(n)+n \ge n$. In other words, any function from the naturals can be "transformed" into another one satisfying the constraint.